# Find the date when a milestone was achieved

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have people that do many multi-day assignments (date x to date Y). I would like to find the date that they completed a milestone e.g. 50 days work completed.

Data is stored as a single row per Assignment
AssignmentId
StartDate
EndDate

I can sum up the total days they have completed up to a date, but am struggling to see how I would find out the date that a milestone was hit. e.g. How many people completed 50 days in October 2020 showing the date within the month that this occurred?

Thanks in advance

PS. Our database is SQL Server.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired resuls, as tabular text. There is more than one way to understand your requirement. Also, what is the query you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by prwvious comments, it would be much easier to help you if you could provide example data and table structure in order help you answer this question.
However, guessing a simple DB structure with a table for your peolple, your tasks and the work each user completed, you can get the required sum of days by use of a date table (or cte) which contains a entry for each day and the window function `SUM` with `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @people TABLE(
  id int
 ,name nvarchar(50)
)

DECLARE @tasks TABLE(
  id int
 ,name nvarchar(50)
)

DECLARE @work TABLE(
  people_id int
 ,task_id int
 ,task_StartDate date
 ,task_EndDate date
)

INSERT INTO @people VALUES (1, 'Peter'), (2, 'Paul'), (3, 'Mary');
INSERT INTO @tasks VALUES (1, 'Devleopment'), (2, 'QA'), (3, 'Sales');

INSERT INTO @work VALUES
  (1, 1, '2019-04-05', '2019-04-08')
 ,(1, 1, '2019-05-05', '2019-06-08')
 ,(1, 1, '2019-07-05', '2019-09-08')
 ,(2, 2, '2019-04-08', '2019-06-08')
 ,(2, 2, '2019-09-08', '2019-10-03')
 ,(3, 1, '2019-11-01', '2019-12-01')

;WITH cte AS(
  SELECT CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE) AS dateday
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, dateday)
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, dateday) < '2020-01-01'
),
cteWorkDays AS(
SELECT people_id, task_id, dateday, 1 AS cnt
  FROM @work w
  INNER JOIN cte c ON c.dateday BETWEEN w.task_StartDate AND w.task_EndDate
),
ctePeopleWorkdays AS(
SELECT *, SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY people_id ORDER BY dateday ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) dayCnt
  FROM cteWorkDays
)
SELECT *
  FROM ctePeopleWorkdays
  WHERE dayCnt = 50
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - great solution. Apologies for lack of clarity regarding data structure in original post. Have learned a lot :-)   
Thanks again

Comment: Then it would be great if you could accept this solution. ::-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on how you store your data. The solution below *assumes* that each worked day exists as a single row in your data model.

The approach below uses a common table expression (`cte`) to generate a running total (`Total`) for each person (`PersonId`) and then filters on the milestone target (I set it to 5 to reduce the sample data size) and target month.

**Sample data**

```
create table WorkedDays
(
  PersonId int,
  TaskDate date
);

insert into WorkedDays (PersonId, TaskDate) values
(100, '2020-09-01'),
(100, '2020-09-02'),
(100, '2020-09-03'),
(100, '2020-09-04'),
(100, '2020-09-05'), -- person 100 worked 5 days by 2020-09-05 = milestone (in september)

(200, '2020-09-29'),
(200, '2020-09-30'),
(200, '2020-10-01'),
(200, '2020-10-02'),
(200, '2020-10-03'), -- person 200 worked 5 days by 2020-10-03 = milestone (in october)
(200, '2020-10-04'),
(200, '2020-10-05'),
(200, '2020-10-06'),

(300, '2020-10-10'),
(300, '2020-10-11'),
(300, '2020-10-12'),
(300, '2020-10-13'),
(300, '2020-10-14'), -- person 300 worked 5 days by 2020-10-14 = milestone (in october)
(300, '2020-10-15'),

(400, '2020-10-20'),
(400, '2020-10-21'); -- person 400 did not reach the milestone yet
```

**Solution**

```
with cte as
(
  select wd.PersonId,
         wd.TaskDate,
         count(1) over(partition by wd.PersonId
                       order by wd.TaskDate
                       rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Total
  from WorkedDays wd
)
select cte.PersonId,
       cte.TaskDate as MileStoneDate
from cte
where cte.Total = 5              -- milestone reached
  and year(cte.TaskDate) = 2020
  and month(cte.TaskDate) = 10;  -- in october
```

**Result**

```
PersonId MilestoneDate
-------- -------------
200      2020-10-03
300      2020-10-14
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=20acadf89b7bd9b0cd5572c574486c3f) (also shows the common table expression output).

Comment: Thanks for this great solution - apologies for not being clearer in the original question regarding my data structure - have learned a lot today :-)
Thank you